# Set up persistent code folding on Monaco editor

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

I'm trying to set up persistent code folding on the Monaco editor and I'm not sure how to:

- extract the view state when it changes;
- store it in localstorage;
- and then restore from that when Monaco is mounted.

I know about `saveViewState` and `restoreViewState`, but I'm not sure how to get notified that the view state has changed so that I can call `saveViewState`.

How should I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no notification. You have to identify a good point in time when to query the view state, usually right before you destroy the editor or update it with new state.